# How to detect that my application is running in VS 2008 with debugger attached?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, debugging

Previously I was doing a lot of WinForms components and we had something like "InDesigner". I'm wondering if there is something similar like "IsWithDebuggerAttached".

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? There's probably a better way of doing it than detecting the debugger. Conditional compilation attributes, etc. A more complete description would make it easier to find the right hammer.

Comment: I do some wired stuff with TopShelf and if WhenStarted takes to much is failing with timeout exception

Comment: I honestly don't know what those things are. I assume TopShelf is some kind of third-party class library? What does the `WhenStarted` method do? Why does it only fail when the debugger is attached? Can you modify the source for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could investigate [System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.aspx). This will tell you whether or not a debugger is attached to your application. Whether or not it's Visual Studio is another story.

Answer (score 1):

From the the `System.Diagnostics` namespace, use the `Debugger.IsAttached` property.